# how to calculate two coordinates distance in objective c?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

as title how to? i have tried the code from google earth, but seem like the result is different with the google map calculation result. below provided the code i did

```
-(double)GetDistance:(double)lat1 long1:(double)lng1 la2:(double)lat2 long2:(double)lng2 {
    //NSLog(@"latitude 1:%.7f,longitude1:%.7f,latitude2:%.7f,longtitude2:%.7f",lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2);
    double radLat1 = [self rad:lat1];
    double radLat2 = [self rad:lat2];
    double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
    double b = [self rad:lng1] -[self rad:lng2];
    double s = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(a/2),2) + cos(radLat1)*cos(radLat2)*pow(sin(b/2),2)));
    s = s * EARTH_RADIUS;
    s = round(s * 10000) / 10000;
    return s;
}

-(double)rad:(double)d
{
    return d *3.14159265 / 180.0;
}
```

the EARTH_RADIUS value is 6378.138

by using this function by provided two coordinates the result come out is 4.5kM
but when i use google map get direction between two same coordinates, it show me the distance  is about 8km

can anyone help to point out the problem of my code?

Comment: First question would be where did you get the equation from?

Comment: What query do you enter into Google Maps to check that?  It might be telling you the driving distance, whereas you're calculating the distance as the crow flies.

Comment: @Nick, that's the common formula for this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance for a good discussion of it.

Comment: Following up on the other comments, can you post the input coordinates you're using and the Google query you're testing against?

Comment: You need to use the 'distanceFrom' function in the Google Maps API.  Don't use directions.

Answer (score 50):

Since this is tagged iPhone, why not use the built-in distance function rather than rolling your own? location1 and location2 are CLLocation objects.

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2];
```

Comment: For anything older than iOS 3.2: [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]

Comment: In iOS 7.1 `[location1 getDistanceFrom:location2]` is deprecated. I'm using `[location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]`.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple code (supposing you just have latitude and longitude of the two points)

```
CLLocation *startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:startLatitude longitude:startLongitude];
CLLocation *endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:endLatitude longitude:endLongitude];
CLLocationDistance distance = [startLocation distanceFromLocation:endLocation]; // aka double
```

Don't forget to add MapKit Framework to your project, and import MapKit in your file :

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

Google Maps is likely to be giving you the driving distance, whereas the great circle equation you have listed is going to be the straight line surface distance.  If there was a straight line surface road directly from point A to point B, Google Maps would likely give you the same distance as the equation you have there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) directly to calculate either great circle distance or driving distance depending on your application needs.

See `GLatLong::distanceFrom` and `GDirections::getDistance`.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
getDistanceFrom:
```

isDeprecated
Try use the

`[newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation`