# Calculating the distance between two annotations: iOS 5

Tags: google-maps, ios5, mapkit, xcode4.3, cllocation

I am able to drop two annotations(source, destination) for the required points. But, now I want to determine the distance between them. I looked for the solution and came across one on :
[Calculating distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980898/how-to-calculate-two-coordinates-distance-in-objective-c)

but the solution:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2];
```

`getDistanceFrom:` is deprecated in iOS 5. Please can anybody suggest me a way to do so using Google Maps API to find the actual distance between the points

While looking up for options, I came across another solution:

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];

        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate2.latitude longitude:coordinate2.longitude];

        CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
        NSLog(@"DISTANCE : %f", distance/1000);
```

But, I am not sure whether this solution is correct. The distance that it returns is it the actual distance between source and destination by road? I tried comparing it on google maps, it approximately matches. Please verify if its the correct approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: distanceFromLocation uses a straight line (along the surface of a spherical earth), not a road route.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:

Comment: Please suggest me a way that I can use in finding the distance along the road

Answer (score 3):

How about `distanceFromLocation:`?

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

Comment: I tried :CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:location2];
            NSLog(@"Distance is: %f", distance);
But it returns 0.00000

Answer (score 3):

distanceFromLocation: Method work fine in my code

> ** Distance display in meter

```
 CLLocation *location =[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[@"23.039698" doubleValue] longitude:[@"72.571663" doubleValue]];
 CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[@"23.0422" doubleValue] longitude:[@"72.5644" doubleValue]];
 CLLocationDistance distanceMeter = [location distanceFromLocation:loc];
```