# Objective C compare two CGPoint to see if they are close?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

So I currently get the location of a touch by using

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

Now what I want to do is check the location on the next touch to see if the locations are close, say 25 points on x or y axis.

There are a few posts that show how to compare if two touches are equivalent but is there to calculate the distance between multiple points? Any info would be awesome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980898/how-to-calculate-two-coordinates-distance-in-objective-c

Comment: Did you search for distance and cgpoint? I find several hundred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To estimate the distance between two CGPoints, you can make use of simple Pythagorean formula:

```
CGFloat dX = (p2.x - p1.x);
CGFloat dY = (p2.y - p1.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY));
```

Comment: ... with the usual observation: to compare the distance to 25 points, don't do `distance < 25`, skip the square root (yes, they're still 'expensive') and do `squareDistance < 25*25`. I don't think you'd gain anything significant from switching to Manhattan distance nowadays for this sort of calculation.