# How can I calculate distance origin lat long to destination lat long of polyline points on google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-polyline

I wanted to find the distance between the origin lat long and destination lat long of the Polyline i have drawn using google api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate two coordinates distance in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980898/how-to-calculate-two-coordinates-distance-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Form CLLocation object like

```
 CLLocation *sourceLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:sourceCoordinate.latitude longitude:sourceCoordinate.longitude];

CLLocation *destinationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude longitude:destinationCoordinate.longitude];
```

and pass them to this method.

```
-(CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFromSource:(CLLocation*)source andDestination:(CLLocation*)destination {
    CLLocationDistance distance = [source distanceFromLocation:destination];
    return  distance;
}
```